# Ошибка 1 error C2660: trans: функция не принимает 2 аргументов

Tags: c++, функции

```
#include <std_lib_facilities.h>
#include <clocale>

double trans();

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    double x=' ',z=' ',r=' ';
    char unit ='a';

    while (cin>>x>>unit)
    {
        trans(x, unit);
        if (x<z)
        {
            z=x;
            cout <<"Наименьшее среди введенных\n";
        }
        else if (x>r)
        {
            r=x;
            cout <<"Наибольшее среди введенных\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

double trans(double x,char unit)
{
    switch (unit)
    {
    case 'cm':
        unit ='m';
        x = x/100;
        break;
    case 'in':
        unit ='m';
        x = x/254;
        break;
    case 'ft':
        unit ='m';
        x = x/3048;
        break;
    case 'm':
        x = x;
        break;
    default:
        cout <<"Неизвестное значение\n";
        break;
    }
    return x,unit;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сообщение об ошибке означает, что вы сначала объявили функцию `trans`, как не имеющую параметры

```
double trans();
```

Однако затем в теле функции main вызываете ее с двумя аргументами

```
trans(x, unit);
```

У вас объявление функции `trans` перед функцией `main` не соответствует определению этой же функции, которое следует после `main`.

Тем не менее даже если вы исправите эту ошибку, ваша программа содержит другие ошибки и не имеет смысла.

Например, данная инициализация переменных

```
double x=' ',z=' ',r=' ';
```

бессмысленна. Значения этих переменных будут содержать значение кода символа пробела, которое, например, в таблице ASCII равно 32.

Далее, в метках `case` у вас используется многобайтовые символьные литералы

```
case 'cm':
```

Они имеют тип `int` в то время как в объекте `unit` типа `char` может храниться только один байт. Поэтому ни одно сравнение не будет выполнено.

К тому же, как я понимаю, вы должны вывести наибольшее и наименьшее значения после цикла, а не при каждой итерации цикла.

Если я правильно понял задание, то программа может выглядеть следующим образом (вы можете включить дополнительно ваши заголовки в программу)

В программе используются объекты классов `std::pair` и `std::string`. Это упрощает написание программы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

std::pair<double, std::string> trans( const std::pair<double, std::string> & );

int main() 
{
    std::pair<double, std::string> value;
    std::pair<double, std::string> min( 0.0, "m" );
    std::pair<double, std::string> max( 0.0, "m" );
    bool empty_sequence = true;

    while ( std::cin >> value.first >> value.second )
    {
        std::pair<double, std::string> tmp = trans( value );

        if ( tmp.second != "undefined" )
        {
            if ( empty_sequence || tmp.first < min.first )
            {
                min = value;
            }

            if ( empty_sequence || max.first < tmp.first )
            {
                max = value;
            }
        }

        empty_sequence = false;
    }

    if ( !empty_sequence )
    {
        std::cout <<"Наименьшее среди введенных: " << min.first << min.second << std::endl;
        std::cout <<"Наибольшее среди введенных: " << max.first << max.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

std::pair<double, std::string> trans( const std::pair<double, std::string> &value )
{
    std::pair<double, std::string> tmp( 0.0, "m" );


    if ( value.second == "cm" )
    {
        tmp.first = value.first / 100.0;
    }
    else if ( value.second == "in" )
    {
        tmp.first = value.first / 254.0;
    }       
    else if ( value.second == "ft" )
    {
        tmp.first = value.first / 3048.0;
    }
    else if ( value.second == "m" )
    {
        tmp.first = value.first;
    }
    else
    {
        tmp.second = "undefined";
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

Если ввести, например, следующие значения

```
1 m 120 cm 450 ft 1200 in
```

то результирующий вывод на консоль будет

```
Наименьшее среди введенных: 1200in
Наибольшее среди введенных: 120cm
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы объявили

```
double trans();
```

`trans` как функцию **без параметров**. А потом что-то в нее передаете... Вот компилятор и ругается.

Объявите такой, какой она по факту является:

```
double trans(double, char);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все заработало!